# excel copying unique values to new worksheet

Tags: excel, function

I have a worksheet with many rows/columns like so:

[image]

How can I only copy the unique values from this sheet to a blank one using a function?
I only need the row with first occurence, the rest do not matter.

Comment: Basically I want the same functionality as copying the whole worksheet and then clicking Remove Duplicates.

Comment: Data tab >> sort & filter >> advanced >> copy to another location + unique records only.   Why do you need to do this with a function?

Comment: I agree with Tim. Use the advanced button on the sort & filter section of the Data tab. You don't need a function.

Comment: i am too with Tim on this or a vba solution, resulting in a function doing what you wrote in your comment - doing this only with worksheet functions, heck I want too see a solution for that :)

Comment: Does the Data tab >> sort & filter >> advanced >> copy to another location + unique records only work with multiple columns? I tried but it didnt work.

Comment: @gammay - no, you can use it on a single column - tested this. Used A:A as source; A1 as criteria; copied to B:B

Comment: @Jook: yes, it works for a single column but the question asks for "I only need the row with first occurence". The copied table should contain the entire row of the first occurrence.

Comment: @gammay: ok, that is right - to get the whole row, you would have to use vlookup with the duplicatefree id data for each other col. At this point - why not use pivotTable?! And of course, now i see way more use in your answer ;) mybe you should update it a bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a formula in the next column to indicate if the value already occurs in the cells above. See below:

[image]

Add this formula to all cells except the first row. Now you can filter for cells that do not contain "DUP" and copy-paste the filtered list to another sheet.

Comment: @Jook Please see my comment above

Answer (score 0):

I normally use the method Tim Williams has suggested, but I found this on another stack thread.

[Ignore Duplicates and Create New List of Unique Values in Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13307927/ignore-duplicates-and-create-new-list-of-unique-values-in-excel)

```
=INDEX(Sheet1!$A$1:$A$20, MATCH(0, COUNTIF($B$1:B1,Sheet!$A$1:$A$20), 0))
```

I found this really useful for lists which grow. You need to ensure you pull it down far enough to capture all the results, and you get NA#'s beyond the number of correct results. But you can handle that with and if(iserror( or a bit of VBA.