# Ignore Duplicates and Create New List of Unique Values in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I have a column of values that often appear as duplicates. I need to create a new column, of unique values based on the first column, as follows:

```
Column A   Column B  
a          a
a          b
b          c
c
c
```

This Column B will actually need to appear on a different sheet, within the same workbook, so I assume it will need to work with the `sheet2!A1` style format.

I have not had any luck with the Data/Filter menu options as this only seems to work on command. I need column B to update automatically whenever a new value is entered into column A.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Totero's answer is correct. The link is also very helpful.

Basically the formula you need is:

```
B2=INDEX($A$2:$A$20, MATCH(0, COUNTIF($B$1:B1, $A$2:$A$20), 0))
```

Then press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>enter</kbd> (or it will not work using a array formula).

Two important things to keep in mind here: The complete list is in cells `A2:A20`, then this formula has to be pasted in cell `B2` (Not `B1` as that will give you circular reference).
Secondly this is an array formula, so you need to press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>enter</kbd> or it will not work correctly.

Comment: How to get rid of N/A and 0's?

Comment: @MoritzSchmitzv.Hülst Get rid of the `#N/A`s with `IFERROR(...,"")` and get rid of the `0` by using specifying the range correctly, i.e. the `$A$2:$A$20` in the example, if you need it to be dynamic then use `OFFSET`

Comment: What does B2 do in this formula?  It is not relative to anything in my sheet and I only get N/A all the way through.

Comment: Oh I resolved by pressing CTRL Shift & Enter, but now I only get one name

Comment: And what about if I want to copy that content to a different sheet?

Comment: To clarify, in B1 you enter `=A1`, in B2 you enter `=INDEX($A$2:$A$20, MATCH(0, COUNTIF($B$1:B1, $A$2:$A$20), 0))`, in B3 you enter `INDEX($A$2:$A$20, MATCH(0, COUNTIF($B$1:B2, $A$2:$A$20), 0))`, etc.  Notice that the only thing that is changing is :B1, and that's why it's marked as relative.

Answer (score 21):

There is a good guide of how to do this [here](http://www.get-digital-help.com/2009/03/30/how-to-extract-a-unique-list-and-the-duplicates-in-excel-from-one-column/).

Basically Something similar to:

```
=INDEX(Sheet1!$A$1:$A$20, MATCH(0, COUNTIF($B$1:B1,Sheet!$A$1:$A$20), 0))
```

Comment: Hi Totero, certainly this formula seems to apply to what I want to do, but it is returning a 'Circular Reference Warning' and simply displaying 0 in each cell. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Circular reference means that your formula is in a cell, which is referred by the same formula. Just check that the formula is not in range A1:A20 or cell B1.

Answer (score 10):

In my case the excel was frozen when using the formula of

> B2=INDEX($A$2:$A$20, MATCH(0, COUNTIF($B$1:B1, $A$2:$A$20), 0))

because there was many rows (10000). So I did in another way which I show below.

I have copied my original list to a second column and then with the function of Excel "remove duplicates" I could find the list of unique values.

Copied from Microsoft Office Website:

> ```
> Select all the rows, including the column headers, in the list
> ```
>
> you want to filter.
>
> Click the top left cell of the range, and then drag to the bottom right cell.
>
> ```
> On the Data menu, point to Filter, and then click Advanced Filter.
> In the Advanced Filter dialog box, click Filter the list, in place.
> Select the Unique records only check box, and then click OK.
> ```
>
> The filtered list is displayed and the duplicate rows are hidden.
>
> ```
> On the Edit menu, click Office Clipboard.
> ```
>
> The Clipboard task pane is displayed.
>
> ```
> Make sure the filtered list is still selected, and then click Copy Copy button.
> ```
>
> The filtered list is highlighted with bounding outlines and the selection appears as an > > item at the top of the Clipboard.
>
> ```
> On the Data menu, point to Filter, and then click Show All.
> ```
>
> The original list is re-displayed.
>
> ```
> Press the DELETE key.
> ```
>
> The original list is deleted.
>
> ```
> In the Clipboard, click on the filtered list item.
> ```
>
> The filtered list appears in the same location as the original list.

Source:
Microsoft Office Website (link removed, cause dead)

Comment: Low tech and very effective. Remember NOT to clear the filter before copying and pasting (probably obvious to most of you, but I was caught the first time!)

Comment: The link is here: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Filter-for-unique-values-or-remove-duplicate-values-ccf664b0-81d6-449b-bbe1-8daaec1e83c2

Answer (score 5):

On a ***sorted column***, you can also try this idea:

```
B2=A2
B3=IFERROR(INDEX(A:A,MATCH(B2,A:A,1)+1),"")
```

B3 can be pasted down. It will result 0, after the last unique match. If this is unwanted, put some IF statement around to exclude this.

**Edit:**

Easier than an IF statement, at least for text-values:

```
B3=IFERROR(T(INDEX(A:A,MATCH(B2,A:A,1)+1)),"")
```

Comment: your formula fails if data is "a
a
b
b
c
c
e
d
d"

Comment: @FahimParkar yeah, I know, as I said: "On a sorted column"

Comment: ohh, I didn't noticed that. Better to highlight such point (which are imp)

Comment: you welcome. Usually everyone will just pick the code and write. No one read (atleast myself) all texts. so better highlight the imp point. Enjoy SO...

Answer (score 5):

To remove duplicates from a column

1. Sort the values in column A A->Z
2. Select column B
3. While column B is still selected, in the formula input box, enter

   ```
   =IF(TRIM(A1)=TRIM(A2),"",TRIM(A1))
   ```
4. While Column B is still selected, select Edit -> Fill -> Down  (in newer versions, simply select cell B1 and pull down the outer box to expand all the way down in the column)

***Note***: if column B is on another sheet, you may do Sheet1!A1 and Sheet1!A2.

Answer (score 3):

```
=SORT(UNIQUE(A:A))
```

The above formula works best if you want to list unique values in a column.

Comment: FYI, `UNIQUE()` is only available in Office 365, not in older Excels.

Answer (score 2):

In the worksheet module for the sheet containing the list:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim rngDest As Range

    If Not Intersect(Target, Me.Columns(1)) Is Nothing Then

        Set rngDest = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1")

        Me.Range(Me.Range("A2"), Me.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)).AdvancedFilter _
            Action:=xlFilterCopy, CopyToRange:=rngDest, Unique:=True

    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

I have a list of color names in range A2:A8, in column B I want to extract a distinct list of color names.

Follow the below given steps:

- Select the Cell B2; write the formula to retrieve the unique values from a list.
- `=IF(COUNTIF(A$2:A2,A2)=1,A2,””)`
- Press <kbd>Enter</kbd> on your keyboard.
- The function will return the name of the first color.
- To return the value for the rest of cells, copy the same formula down. To copy formula in range B3:B8, copy the formula in cell B2 by pressing the key <kbd>CTRL+C</kbd> on your keyboard and paste in the range B3:B8 by pressing the key <kbd>CTRL+V</kbd>.
- Here you can see the output where we have the unique list of color names.

Comment: This leaves gaps

Answer (score 0):

So for this task First Sort your data in order from A to Z or Z to A then you can just use one simple formula as stated below:

```
=IF(A2=A3, "Duplicate", "Not Duplicate")
```

The above formula states that if column A2 data ( A is column and 2 is row number) is similar to A3 (A is Column and 3 is Row number) then it will print Duplicate else will print Not Duplicate.

Lets consider an example, Column A consists Email address in which some are duplicate, so in Column 2, I used the above stated formula which in results displayed me the 2 duplicates cells one is Row 2 and Row 6.

One you got the duplicate data just put filter on your sheet and make visible only the duplicate data and delete all the unnecessary data.

Answer (score 0):

Honestly I followed these examples to a tee and they simply didn't work.  What I ended up doing after struggling pointlessly trying to get Excel to work was to just copy the entire contents of my column to NotePad++ where I was able to find an easy solution within minutes.  Take a look at this:  [Removing duplicate rows in Notepad++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3958350/removing-duplicate-rows-in-notepad)

Edit: Here is a brief overview of how to do it in TextFX:

Plugins -> Plugin Manager -> Show Plugin Manager -> Available tab -> TextFX -> Install

After TextFX is installed in NotePad++, then you select all your text you want to remove duplicates from, then make sure to check:  TextFX -> TextFX Tools -> Sort outputs only UNIQUE lines

Then click "sort lines case sensitive" or "sort lines case insensitive" and it will perform the unique sort.

Answer (score 0):

Find [here](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/4032-excel-dynamic-list-of-unique-values.html) mentioned above formula with error control

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($B$2:$B$9, MATCH(0,COUNTIF($D$1:D1, $B$2:$B$9), 0)),"")
```

where: (B2:B9 is the column data which you want to extract the unique values, D1 is the above cell where your formula is located)

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is :
Go to Data tab
Chose advanced in Sort & Filter
In actions select : copy to another location if want a new list
- Copy to any location 
In list range chose the list you want to get the records off . 
And the most important  thing is to check :
Unique records only .

Answer (score 0):

Another approach, since Excel 2016, is to use Power Query.

Howto:

- select the data (including the field name),
- use menu `Data` > `From a table or a range`,
- (Excel will change your sheet into an Excel Table, which is very convenient),
- in the Power Query Editor, right-click on ColumnA (the column header), and `Remove duplicates`,
- in the menu, choose `Close and load`, choose where you want the result, and you're done, [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v8gbh.png).
- Whenever you want the result table to update, right-click it and choose `Refresh`.

Benefits :

- it uses the CPU only when manually updated, which is very convenient
  for long lists,
- if you're curious, this offers many other powerful
  options.

Drawbacks :

- it doesn't update on the fly (you have to right-click and refresh the
  result table),
- people with old version of Excel won't be able to refresh the results table.

Answer (score -6):

The MODERN approach is to consider cases where column of information come from a web service such as an OData source. If you need to generate a filter select fields off of massive data that has replicated values for the column, consider the code below:

```
var CatalogURL = getweb(currenturl)
                 +"/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Site%20Inventory%20and%20Assets')/items?$select=Expense_x0020_Type&$orderby=Expense_x0020_Type";

/* the column that is replicated, is ordered by <column_name> */

    OData.read(CatalogURL,
        function(data,request){

            var myhtml ="";
            var myValue ="";

            for(var i = 0; i < data.results.length; i++)
            {
                myValue = data.results[i].Expense_x0020_Type;

                if(i == 0)
                {
                        myhtml += "<option value='"+myValue+"'>"+myValue+"</option>";
                }
                else
                if(myValue != data.results[i-1].Expense_x0020_Type)
                {
                        myhtml += "<option value='"+myValue+"'>"+myValue+"</option>";

                }
                else
                {

                }


            }

            $("#mySelect1").append(myhtml);

        });
```