# Ignore Duplicates and Create New List of Unique Values in different Sheet in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formula, excel-2013

I am trying to do exactly what was asked in this thread

[Ignore Duplicates and Create New List of Unique Values in Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13307927/ignore-duplicates-and-create-new-list-of-unique-values-in-excel)

**Except it wasn't answered fully. I would like the output in a different sheet.
The question:**

"
I have seen this question asked in various forms numerous times before, but nothing I have tried is working for me.

I have a column of values that often appear as duplicates. I need to create a new column, of unique values based on the first column, as follows...

```
Column A   Column B  
a          a
a          b
b          c
c
c
```

This Column B will actually need to appear on a different sheet, within the same workbook, so I assume it will need to work with the `sheet2!A1` style format.

I have not had any luck with the Data/Filter menu options as this only seems to work on command. I need column B to update automatically whenever a new value is entered into column A. 
"

**The best answer given is:**

"
Basically the formula you need is:

```
B2=INDEX($A$2:$A$20, MATCH(0, COUNTIF($B$1:B1, $A$2:$A$20), 0))
```

Then press ctrl-shift-enter.

Two important things to keep in mind here: The complete list is in cells `A2:A20`, then this formula has to be pasted in cell `B2` (Not `B1` as that will give you circular reference).
Secondly this is an array formula, so you need to press ctrl-shift-enter or it will not work correctly.
"

(This is a useful link: [Unique Values](http://www.get-digital-help.com/2009/03/30/how-to-extract-a-unique-list-and-the-duplicates-in-excel-from-one-column/#unique) )

**Which gives me:**

```
  Column A Col B
    a   a
    a   b
    b   c
    c   d
    c   0
    c   #N/A
    c   #N/A
    b   #N/A
    b   #N/A
    a   
    d   
    d
```

But the output is not in a different sheet.

I have tried a few variations of:

```
=INDEX(List!A2:A20,MATCH(0, COUNTIF(UniqueList!A2:A20,'List'!A2:A20),0))
```

Putting $ signs in:

```
=INDEX(List!$A$2:$A$20,MATCH(0, COUNTIF(UniqueList!$A$2:A20,'List'!$A$2:$A$20),0))
```

Including 'press ctrl-shift-enter'.

But I can't figure it out.

Please help me take a column from List to UniqueList with only the unique values.

Thanks.

Comment: Why not copy the list to a new sheet and use Data | Remove Duplicates?

Comment: That's what I currently do, but I'd like not to have to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me. However, this assumes you have identical column header

```
=INDEX(Sheet1!$A$2:Sheet1!$A$5,MATCH(0,INDEX(COUNTIF($A$1:A1,Sheet1!$A$2:Sheet1!$A$5),0,0),0))
```

Comment: So, I have been getting errors. I think I've figured out why. It because my List is about 100,000 rows. And it takes ages, (minutes), for excel to compute the ones which are unique. I guess I should be using a numeric identifier instead of the 60 character long list name. Any other suggestions?