# Condensing multiple entries in excel into one row

Tags: excel, reduce

I have a spreadsheet in excel where in the leftmost column I have order numbers and the corresponding cell to each cell in the order number columns contain the dollar amount for that particular order. Orders from the same customer have the same order number but different dollar amounts and listed separately in the spreadsheet. Is there a way to systematically condense these orders into a single order for each customer with a corresponding dollar amount equal to the sum of all the orders?

```
order number    Dollar Amount           order number    dollar amount
1234                $100                     1234         $1,000 
1234                $200                     2345         $1,100 
1234                $300                
1234                $400                
2345                $500                
2345                $600
```

Comment: just added an example @janaspage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go for the other solutions (acher's & pnuts') but if you absolutely have to use formulas, this might help:

[image]

Result:

[image]

**Formulas:**

Column C (Array formula, confirm with Ctrl+Shift+Enter):

```
=INDEX($A$2:$A$20,MATCH(0,COUNTIF($C$1:C1,$A$2:$A$20),0))
```

Column D

```
=SUMIF($A$2:$A$7,C2,$B$2:$B$7)
```

[Useful link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13307927/ignore-duplicates-and-create-new-list-of-unique-values-in-excel) for the formula on column C.

I hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

There is an easy way without any functions or script to do this, but doesn't look exactly like what you want.

Please see steps below:

1. Sort the data in `order number`
2. Select the the columns `order number` and `Dollar Amount`
3. Go to Data -> Subtotal
4. Select the following settings:

[image: Subtotal Settings]

You should now have all the information you are asking for just not in a separate column. It should look like this.

```
order number    Dollar Amount
1234    $100 
1234    $200 
1234    $300 
1234    $400 
1234 Total  $1,000 
2345    $500 
2345    $600 
2345 Total  $1,100 
Grand Total $2,100
```

Comment: I can add a screen shot of the settings to make this clearer once I have enough reputation to do so.

Comment: @pnuts I believe that using the subtotal functionality will automatically sort the data appropriately.

Comment: You are absolutely right, can't believe I just got lucky all these years with my data being ordered. Let me add that step in.

Comment: Thank you, and you are right this and further analysis could be made much easier with a pivot table.

Answer (score 0):

Create a unique list of order numbers (eg with DATA > Sort & Filter - Advanced, Copy to another location List range: $A:$A, Copy to: E1, tick Unique records only) then in say F2 and copied down:

```
 =SUMIF(A:A,E2,B:B)
```

Comment: could you break down what you are doing a little more, I am confused on your solution