# Reduce an excel 2d table to a single row 'list' (and remove the duplicates

Tags: excel, duplicates

I have a table.

```
    1       2       3       4
A   red     purple  green   red
B   blue    yellow  white   brown
C   pink    green   purple  red
D   pink    pink    orange  white
E   green   red     hazel   black
F   orange  orange  blue    orange
```

I want to return (into a range) a list of every colour that appears (but only one entry in the list per colour, so no duplicates).  I have found many answers for the single col version, but I really would like to extend to 2D.  I would prefer an array formula solution than a VBA solution (though I'll give it a go).
see this for example.

[Ignore Duplicates and Create New List of Unique Values in Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13307927/ignore-duplicates-and-create-new-list-of-unique-values-in-excel)

The table may occupy any position on a sheet!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To extract uniques from a two-dimensional table, see:

[Coderre Formula](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2003-excel/extract-unique-data-from-table/1ba1796a-c647-e011-9575-d8d385dcbb12)

**EDIT#1:**

In this example the *4X6* table is in **C4** thru **F9**

The *helper column* is **H4** thru **H27**
The *Uniques* are in column **I** starting in **I4**

In **H4** enter:

```
=OFFSET($C$4,ROUNDUP(ROWS($1:1)/4,0)-1,MOD(ROWS($1:1)-1,4))
```

and copy down

In **I4** enter:

```
=H4
```

In **I5** enter the array formula:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($H$5:$H$27, MATCH(0, COUNTIF($I$4:I4, $H$5:$H$27), 0)),"")
```

and copy down

**Array formulas** must be entered with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> rather than just the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key.

Here is what we see:

[image]

Comment: Do you have a solution for a case where the table does not occupy the top left of the sheet.  I didn't mean to imply this situation with my row/col layout above!

Answer (score 0):

Might be achieved by entering something ("z" would do) at the intercept of `1` and `A`, then creating a PivotTable with multiple consolidation ranges (see for [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20541905/convert-matrix-to-3-column-table-flatten)) and in the new sheet apply Advanced Filter to the Value column, Copy to another location, Copy to: where desired and select Unique records only. The PT and drill-down details can then be deleted.

Answer (score 0):

This has become very easy in modern Excel.  You can use UNIQUE on a list, and there are a few options for getting the data all in one list.  For a sample list like this:

[image]

You could use VSTACK to combine the columns and then apply UNIQUE, like so:

[image]

```
=UNIQUE(VSTACK(R1C1:R3C1, R1C2:R3C2, R1C3:R3C3))
```

Or you could use TOCOL, like so:

[image]

```
=UNIQUE(TOCOL(R1C1:R3C3))
```