# How to choose high value from a name?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Suppose a plan which contains the scores of a mini game sorted by players' name.

[image]

How to get the best score for each player?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a combination of `Max` and `If`:

In E1, place this formula (and enter by pressing `CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER`) and drag down:
`=MAX(IF($A$2:$A$11=$D2,$B$2:$B$11))`

(Edit per @ExcelHero's comment, I had $D9).

Comment: I guess you mean `=$D2`

Answer (score 1):

You could also sort the list by score in descending order and then just do a `vlookup` as in

```
=vlookup(D1, $A$1:$B$11, 2, false)
```

as `vlookup` will just return the first match.

Comment: Thank you! I'll correct right now. So used to 0-based indices.

Comment: Also, you would want to add false or 0 to the 4th parameter for an exact match. Right now its defaulting to an approximate match and will not always return the appropriate answer.

Comment: I thought about that. I guess I felt it not likely to make a difference. I'll make the edit. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a link to a method that is completely formula driven.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/30733387/1188594

It would use the array formula suggested by @BruceWayne, but also uses a formula that can create a distinct list of players.