# Microsoft Excel - for each unique value in column A, return max value from column C and the corresponding value from B

Tags: excel, max

using a formula, I'm looking to get the max of column C for each unique value in column A then I'd like to also return the corresponding value from column B to the max of column C.  the output should be a summary of the data as in the second screen capture.  I've tried pivot tables, conditional formatting and the help in this link with no luck [Get the maximum values of column B per each distinct value of column A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30732798/get-the-maximum-values-of-column-b-per-each-distinct-value-of-column-a)

[original data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rjxdP.jpg)

[desired result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yn20Y.jpg)

Is this possible with formulas?

Answer (score 0):

So for the Max number use the AGGREGATE() Function:

```
=AGGREGATE(14,6,$C$2:INDEX(C:C,MATCH(1E+99,C:C))/($A$2:INDEX(A:A,MATCH(1E+99,C:C))=I2),1)
```

Then to find the Capacity a simple SUMIF():

```
=SUMIFS(B:B,A:A,I2,C:C,K2)
```

[image]

The AGGREGATE() Function was introduced in Excel 2010.

---

For other versions, the less robust Array Formula MAX(IF()) will work in place of the AGGREGATE:

```
=MAX(IF($A$2:INDEX(A:A,MATCH(1E+99,C:C))=I2,$C$2:INDEX(C:C,MATCH(1E+99,C:C))))
```

Being an Array Formula it must be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter when exiting Edit mode. When done correctly Excel will automatically put {} around the formula to denote an array formula.

Another, If you have the latest Office 365 or using the online app the following non CSE MAXIFS() will work also:

```
=MAXIFS($C$2:INDEX(C:C,MATCH(1E+99,C:C)),$A$2:INDEX(A:A,MATCH(1E+99,C:C)),I2)
```

These two are not as robust as the AGGREGATE() in that they will break if there are errors in the data.  AGGREGATE() will ignore them.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another option using Array formula, in a Table. I didn't do this starting at A1 in my sheet, so the image has my cell/row IDs to assist!

[image: Array formula using Tables, Max, Lists, etc]

Cell M17: `=IFNA(INDEX([Host], MATCH(0, COUNTIF($M$16:M16, [Host]), 0)),"Unknown")` +`Ctrl`+`Shift`+`Enter`

Cell N17: `=MAX(IF([Host]=[@UniqueHost],[Duration]))` +`Ctrl`+`Shift`+`Enter`

Cell O17: `=IFNA(INDEX([Capacity],MATCH([@UniqueHost]&[@MaxDuration],[Host]&[Duration],0)),0)` +`Ctrl`+`Shift`+`Enter`