# Excel - how to look up non-unique names and add the numbers next to them?

Tags: excel

Effectively, I want a vlookup but for multiple things then add it at the end.

For example:

```
      1          2          3                 4
a   Title 1   Name1     Description 1         6
b   Title 2   Name2     Description 2         2
c   Title 2   Name2     Description 2         14
```

Basically, I want to find all of "Name 2" in column 2 then add the number in column 4.  I want to do this to each unique name.

How do I do that?

Comment: Look into the SUMIF function...

Answer (score 1):

MacroMarc and Scott Craner both pointed you in good directions ...

**Method 1 - Formula**

[Also see this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13307927/ignore-duplicates-and-create-new-list-of-unique-values-in-excel)

Assuming you put a header on your table at Row 1, and your data is in Columns A through D, put this CSE formula in `F2` and fill down. (the $20 will change, de

```
=IF(INDEX($B$2:$B$20, MATCH(0, COUNTIF($B$1:B1, $B$2:$B$20), 0))=0,"",INDEX($B$2:$B$20, MATCH(0, COUNTIF($B$1:B1, $B$2:$B$20), 0)))
```

Then put this formula in `G2` and fill down

```
=IF(SUMIF($B$2:$B$20,"="&F2,$D$2:$D$20)=0,"",SUMIF($B$2:$B$20,"="&F2,$D$2:$D$20))
```

You will get a result that looks like this

[image]

**Method 2 - Pivot Table**

Select anywhere inside your table and pick Insert -> Pivot Table. Put it on a new worksheet.

Put the "Name" field in the Rows and the "Count" field in the Values - it will be a SUM by default. You get the following result ...

[image]

Either method takes less than two minutes. 8)