# Select Newest Record and Create New Table of Unique Values in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Excel table that records vehicle progress through work stations within a business. A given work station may be visited more than once.

The vehicle license plate number (Reg No) is used to identify the vehicle, and the user adds a new row to the spreadsheet when the vehicle arrives at the next new work station. As well as the Reg No, each row also has a Record ID.

This workflow means that multiple record rows will be created for a given Reg No.

When all work on a vehicle is complete, the record is cut and archived on another worksheet.

[Current Vehicle Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zOliU.png)

What I want to create is a summary table on another worksheet tab, that displays all rows for vehicles in progress. Where a vehicle currently has a single record, I want to extract that record row, and where a vehicle has multiple records, I want to extract only the last (most recent) record row.

I want the summary to be a “live” reflection of the underpinning data sheet.

From searches I have found formula examples to [Ignore Duplicates and Create New List of Unique Values in Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13307927/ignore-duplicates-and-create-new-list-of-unique-values-in-excel) but these pick the first duplicate value by default, not the last. Search results on “lookup last match” or “return last value” have in common that the user must define the item they are searching for.

I think I need something different because my list of Reg No is not static - it is continually being refreshed by Reg No’s being added and removed (archived).

Acknowledging and understanding Excel is not a database, but if I was thinking in database / SQL terms, my (noob) query might be something like:
SELECT row
WHERE Reg No is unique
AND Record ID is greatest

Do you know of any way to achieve the result I seek, in Excel?

Comment: What version of Excel? How are you populating the data table and specifically the RecordID field - that looks like an AutoNumber from a Database.

Comment: @dbmitch. Excel 2016. RecordID is created by an AutoNumber macro within the workbook. The balance of the table is populated manually. Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use a PivotTable and a lookup formula to accomplish this. Below is some simplified data in an Excel Table (aka ListObject), and below that is a PivotTable with a suitable lookup formula down the right hand side.

[image]

The PivotTable has the Reg No in it as well as the RecordID field in the Values (aggregation) area, set on 'Max'. So basically it displays the maximum RecordID value for each Reg No, and then in the column to the right there's an INDEX/MATCH formula that looks up that RecordID back in the data entry table, and returns the associated Stage.

It's not *quite* live as you will need to refresh the PivotTable, and you need to ensure that you've copied the Lookup formula down far enough to handle the size of the PivotTable.

You can easily automate the refresh simply by putting a Worksheet_Activate event handler in the worksheet. Something like this:
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
    Activesheet.PivotTables("PivotTable").PivotCache.Refresh
End Sub

Since we've now involved VBA, you might as well have some code that copies the formula down the requisite amount of rows beside the PivotTable. I'll whip something up in due course and post it here.

UPDATE: 
I've written some code to slave a Table to a PivotTable, so that any change in the PivotTable's dimensions or placement will be reflected in the shadowing Table's dimensions and placement. This effectively gives us a way to add a *calculated field* to a PivotTable that can refer to something *outside* of that PivotTable, as we're doing here with the INDEX/MATCH lookup. Let's call that functionality a *Calculated Table*.

If the PivotTable grows, the Calculated Table will grow. If the PivotTable shrinks, the Calculated Table will shrink, and any redundant formulas in it will be deleted. Here's how that looks for your example: The top table is from the *Input* sheet, and the PivotTable and Calculated Table below it are from the *Results* sheet.

[image]

If I go to the Input sheet and add some more data, then when I switch back to the Results sheet, the PivotTable automatically gets updated with that new data and the Calculated Table automatically expands to accommodate the extra rows:
[image]

And here's the code I use to automate this:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Report").PivotCache.Refresh
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_PivotTableUpdate(ByVal Target As PivotTable)

    If Target.Name = "Report" Then _
        PT_SyncTable Target, ActiveSheet.ListObjects("SyncedTable")
End Sub


Sub PT_SyncTable(oPT As PivotTable, _
                oLO As ListObject, _
                Optional bIncludeTotal As Boolean = False)

    Dim lLO As Long
    Dim lPT As Long

    'Make sure oLO is in same row
    If oLO.Range.Cells(1).Row <> oPT.RowRange.Cells(1).Row Then
        oLO.Range.Cut Intersect(oPT.RowRange.EntireRow, oLO.Range.EntireColumn).Cells(1, 1)
    End If

    'Resize oLO if required
    lLO = oLO.Range.Rows.Count
    lPT = oPT.RowRange.Rows.Count
    If Not bIncludeTotal And oPT.ColumnGrand Then lPT = lPT - 1
    If lLO <> lPT Then oLO.Resize oLO.Range.Resize(lPT)


    'Clear any old data outside of oLO if it has shrunk
    If lLO > lPT Then oLO.Range.Offset(oLO.Range.Rows.Count).Resize(lLO - lPT).ClearContents

End Sub
```

What's cool is that the code will automatically resize the Calculated Table whenever the PivotTable updates, and those updates are also triggered by you filtering on the PivotTable. So if you filter on just a couple of rego numbers, here's what you see:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You mentioned SQL in your question, so I thought you might be interested in a VBA solution using SQL:

```
'Assumes your data is on a sheet called "DataSheet", and you want the answers stored starting in cell A2 of a sheet called "Results")

Sub test()
    Dim objConnection           As ADODB.Connection
    Dim objRecordset            As ADODB.Recordset

    Set objConnection = New ADODB.Connection
    Set objRecordset = New ADODB.Recordset

    objConnection.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
                                     "Data Source=" & ThisWorkbook.FullName & ";" & _
                                     "Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1"";"

    objConnection.Open

    sqlcommand = "SELECT LAST([Record ID]), " & _
                        "[Reg No], " & _
                        "LAST([Priority Level]), " & _
                        "LAST([Make]), " & _
                        "LAST([Current Stage]) " & _
                        "FROM [DataSheet$] GROUP BY [Reg No]"
    objRecordset.Open sqlcommand, objConnection, adOpenStatic, adLockOptimistic, adCmdText
    Sheets("Results").Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset objRecordset
End Sub
```

To use that, you will need to include References to the "Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 6.1 Library" and "Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects Recordset 6.0 Library" in your VBA project.  (At least, they're the ones I select.)