# Return record in an Excel table that matches criteria

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I have a dataset in an Excel table which looks like this:

```
   ID       Date          BMI
-------  -------------- ---------
1        10/5/1984         35
1        10/5/1985         40
1        10/5/1986         45
2        10/5/1984         28
2        10/5/1985         32
3        10/5/1984         22
```

I want to build a list which outputs each unique ID, and their BMI on their first visit. I would expect that it has something to do with min(date) but I haven't been able to make it work.
I guess I want to have the results look like:

```
ID       BMI at First Visit
-------  --------------
1        35
2        28
3        22
```

Very new, so do please let me know if I need to provide more information, thank you!

Comment: Did either of the answers below solve the issue? If so, can you please mark it as the accepted answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need two array formulas, one to get the unique list and the second to get the corresponding BMI:

To get the ID place this in the second row of column F:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$2:$A$7,MATCH(TRUE,(COUNTIF($F$1:$F1,$A$2:$A$7)=0),0)),"")
```

Confirm with Ctrl-Shift-Enter when exiting edit mode.  If done correctly Excel will put `{}` around the formula.  Then copy down till you get blanks.

[image]

Then reference that column with the array formula for BMI.  Put this in G2:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($C$2:$C$7,MATCH(MIN(IF($A$2:$A$7=F2,$B$2:$B$7)),IF($A$2:$A$7=F2,$B$2:$B$7),0)),"")
```

Confirm with Ctrl-Shift-Enter when exiting edit mode.  If done correctly Excel will put `{}` around the formula.  Then copy down till you get blanks.

[image]

Comment: You're an Excel wizard and I love you, thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you could sort your data on the Date column, and then simply do a VLOOKUP or INDEX/MATCH on each ID, like this:
[image]

Note that the only purpose of the PivotTable is to produce a handy list of the distinct IDs, and the associated date of the first visit. The real work is being done thanks to the Table being sorted by Date ...the INDEX/MATCH formula simply returns the first record it finds in that sorted list.

I elaborate on this approach further at the following SO answer:
[Select Newest Record and Create New Table of Unique Values in Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38859656/select-newest-record-and-create-new-table-of-unique-values-in-excel/38867978#38867978)

In that answer, I go one further, and create a 'Slaved' table that sits alongside the PivotTable in which my lookup formula sits. This Slaved Table  automatically expands or contracts along with the PivotTable. Well worth a look, if I do say so myself.