# How to do a range vlookup using the output of a pivot table column in excel?

Tags: excel, pivot-table, vlookup

These are the monthly salaries of the employees (obtained using the pivot table):

[image]

Each cell will then be used as the `Lookup value` for the `vlookup` or `index and match` functions.

The `lookup value` is to be looked up in  `column A` and `column B` of the table below and if it is matched (within the range), it will return the corresponding value under `column C`.

[image]

I have tried:

1.) Placing this sample formula outside the pivot table:

`=VLOOKUP(GETPIVOTDATA("Sum of Reg Pay",$A4,"Person","JOHN"),SSSContribution[#All],3,TRUE)`

But the problems with the 1st solution are:

a.) The person's name is fixed as string which makes unable to adjust to the drag down.

b.) It is not a calculated field, so every adjustments to the pivot table will require adjustment of the cells containing the formula.

2.) Putting this formula in the `Calculated fields` feature of the pivot table:

`= vlookup( 'Reg Hrs.','SSS Contribution Table'!A$2:D$32,3,TRUE)`, but I get the error below:

[image]

So how to do a range lookup for the output values of a column in a pivot table?

Comment: What version of Excel do you have?

Comment: 2007 at the office. 2016 at home but I can upgrade if there are missing features that is needed in more recent versions

Comment: Okay. If you had Excel 2013 or later you could also use something called the DataModel to do this, all inside the PivotTable using something called DAX formulas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace the entire GETPIVOTDATA function and arguments with the cell reference to the cell concerned, and then copy down. e.g. `=VLOOKUP(E2,SSSContribution[#All],3,TRUE)`

Note that you can turn off the automatic generation of the GETPIVOTDATA syntax by unchecking this option:

[image]

To keep your formula 'synced' to your PivotTable, you'd need to use code something along the lines of this answer of mine:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/38867978/2507160