# Duplicate values in excel

Tags: excel

I have a data set in Excel. I need to be able to find the duplicates in Column A, and where there are duplicates choose the highest value in B corresponding to those duplicate values, and then delete any other duplicates in the range of cells.  Thanks.

```
  100602339        500
**100625802**      100
**100625802**   **9000**
  100628819     150000
  100634286        100
  100634286        300
  100635351       5000
  100635383        300
  100635383       1000
  100635383       7500
```

Comment: I'll admit, I'm a complete amateur.  I've fumbled with IF and VLookup, but to no avail.  I can't even format the question here so it looks similar.

Comment: How big is your data set?

Comment: 130,000 rows, 5 columns

Comment: What if there are duplicates in A but the value in B is the same (e.g. 100625802 100 / 10065802 100)?

Comment: I would need to keep the highest of the numbers in column B.  (e.g. 100625802 100 / 10065802 100:  100625802 1500 / 10065802 1500).  I need 100625802 1500 / 10065802 1500.

Comment: in order to delete you will need to use VBA.  However, if you are willing to generate a new column(s) with just the information you are looking for, then that can be performed with formulas.  Basically generate unique list from column A (this includes existing single entries) and pull the maximum corresponding value from column B.

Comment: It appears I made it more difficult then I needed to.  If you use conditional formatting and sort by color you can cut and paste the individual A column numbers.  Then sort by A smallest to largest, by B largest to smallest and remove duplicates.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

### Formula Option

Desired results are placed in a new columns.

Assuming your list is in range A2:B13

Use the method from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13307927/ignore-duplicates-and-create-new-list-of-unique-values-in-excel) to to generate your list of unique entries in say D2.  Enter the formula and copy down as required.  In E3 place the following formula and copy down as required.

```
D2 CSE formula
=INDEX($A$2:$A$20, MATCH(0, COUNTIF($D$1:D1, $A$2:$A$20), 0))

E2 Regular Formula
=AGGREGATE(14,6,$B$1:$B$11/--($A$1:$A$11=D2),1)
```

CSE formulas require you to press <kbd>CONTROL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> when finishing the formula instead of just <kbd>ENTER</kbd>.  When done right, Excel will automatically add {} around the formula which cannot be added manually.

[image]