# How to extract pure unique values (No duplicate values)?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

> **I want to separate values which appeared only one time in list.**

I am trying to extracting values which do not have any duplicate values. I know how to extract unique values using advance filter, using formulas. But this is new challenge to me.Using a helping column I can do it but trying to do without helping column

[image]

```
ID
00152
00542
00542
00121
00548
00546
00523
00230
00214
00245
00455
00987
00011
00548
0011
00230
00245
00689
00555
00152
00999
00100
```

Comment: And you want this with a normal formula no VBA or VBA function?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ignore Duplicates and Create New List of Unique Values in Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13307927/ignore-duplicates-and-create-new-list-of-unique-values-in-excel)

Comment: I want only formula. I know how to solve it with vba. But due to some constraints I need only excel builtin functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally able to solve the problem. Below is formula to extract pure unique values from a list.

```
=INDEX($B$5:$B$26,AGGREGATE(15,6,(ROW($B$5:$B$26)-ROW($B$4))/(COUNTIF($B$5:$B$26,$B$5:$B$26)=1),ROW(1:1)))
```

Answer (score 1):

If the data is in A2:A23, try this array formula in D2:D23 (or any other column):

```
=INDEX($A$1:$A$23,SMALL(IF(COUNTIF($A$2:$A$23,$A$2:$A$23)=1,ROW($A$2:$A$23),""),ROW($A$1:$A$22)))
```