# Compute average prices of distinct values in a column

Tags: excel

I have an excel dataset like this:

| item | price_dollar_kg |
| --- | --- |
| apple | 1 |
| apple | 1.5 |
| apple | 1.8 |
| apple | 1.3 |
| banana | 30 |
| banana | 1.8 |
| banana | 2 |
| banana | 143 |
| banana | 143 |

But then with about 30,000 entries for about 100 food items. For each item, I want to compute the average price without the outliers (3*IQR). Is there a way in which I can let excel automaticly place the functions I need everytime entries for another food item start in column "item" and let the cell references in these functions adapt to this? Or is there any other way I could easily compute the prices I need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wasn't sure what you meant by 3 * IQR, so the solutions below assume the range is 1Q - IQR and 3Q + IQR for a total span of 3 * IQR.

The first step is the covert you data to a table.  In my example, it is call Table2.

If you have a version of Excel Office 365 that supports LET and dynamic arrays then you can enter `=UNIQUE(Table2[Item])` into D2 to get the list of unique items.

Then in E2 enter the following.

```
=LET(itemList,Table2[Item],
     priceList,Table2[price_dollar_kg],
     item,D2,
     quartiles,QUARTILE(FILTER(priceList,itemList=item),{1,3}),
     IQR,SUM({-1,1}*quartiles),
     avgRange,quartiles+{-1,1}*IQR,avgNoOut,AVERAGEIFS(priceList,itemList,item,priceList,">="&INDEX(avgRange,1),priceList,"<="&INDEX(avgRange,2)),
     IF(item="","",avgNoOut))
```

Then copy E2 down to E3:E201.  This will allow up to 200 unique items.  I couldn't figure out a way to get the formula to spill automatically with the length of the unique list so I made this compromise.

The results looks like this.

[image: Result with O365]

If you version of Excel doesn't support LET or dynamic arrays, you can do the following.

Set Cell D2 = A2.

Set Cell D3 to `=IFERROR(INDEX(Table24[Item],MATCH(0,COUNTIF($D$2:D2,Table24[Item]),0)),"")`. Be sure to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>.  This needs to be an array formula to work correctly.  More info on this formula is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13307927/ignore-duplicates-and-create-new-list-of-unique-values-in-excel).

Then copy the formula down to E4:201.  Again, this gives you room for 200 unique items.

Set Cell F2 to `=IF($D2="","",QUARTILE(IF(Table24[Item]=$D2,Table24[price_dollar_kg],""),1))`.

Set Cell G2 to `=IF($D2="","",QUARTILE(IF(Table24[Item]=$D2,Table24[price_dollar_kg],""),3))`.

Set H2 to `=G2-F2`; I2 to `=F2-H2`; J2 to `=G2+H2`.

Set E2 to `=IF(D2="","",AVERAGEIFS(Table24[price_dollar_kg],Table24[Item],D2,Table24[price_dollar_kg],">="&I2,Table24[price_dollar_kg],"<="&J2))`.

Copy E2:J2 to E3:J201. The final result looks like this.

[image]

Comment: Thank you Axuary, this solved it for me!!!